# Does Star Hound end?

Tags: star-hound

I've gotten to 21,000 meters in [Star Hound](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/star-hound/id592828388?mt=8) and unlocked all the start points. Is there anything else to do? Does the game end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The game ends at 25,000 metres. This is the very end.